# Get stored procedure result inside another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedures. The first one gets a new ID from a database. I need to use these id inside another stored procedure; I can't get this info correctly.

Stored procedure used to get ID:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETNEXTID] 
    @IDRECORD BIGINT,
    @INCREMENT INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE SISTEMA  
    SET TICKET = (TICKET + @INCREMENT) 
    WHERE ID = @IDRECORD;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    SELECT TICKET 
    FROM SISTEMA 
    WHERE ID = @IDRECORD;

    RETURN;
END
```

This is the second stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @IdRecord bigint;
    SET @IdRecord = 0;

    EXECUTE @IdRecord = GETNEXTID 1, 1;

    SELECT 'TEST' = @IdRecord;
END
```

When I try to use the first stored procedure in the second one stored procedure, I get 0 from calling it.

If I use the `GETNEXTID` from my software, I get correct values.

Comment: You're not returning your value from your SP - and you shouldn't be either, the return value is intended to be the status. You want an output parameter.

Comment: Without some kind of locking and correct transaction management, the above design is going to end up with race conditions as well.

Comment: Why aren't you using the inbuilt tools, like `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`?

Comment: a select doesn't return values. you could do:     RETURN(SELECT TICKET 
    FROM SISTEMA 
    WHERE ID = @IDRECORD); in your procedure. But as others mentioned, it's usually better to return values as an extra OUTPUT parameter. Also, your concurrency is not correctly handled

Comment: Thanks Dale. I solved using your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You must use output parameters to return value from stored procedure and put the result in a variable.

So change your stored procedure to something like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETNEXTID] 
    @IDRECORD BIGINT,
    @INCREMENT INT,
    @OutputParameter INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE SISTEMA  
    SET TICKET = (TICKET + @INCREMENT) 
    WHERE ID = @IDRECORD;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    SELECT @OutputParameter = TICKET 
    FROM SISTEMA 
    WHERE ID = @IDRECORD; 
END
```

And then change your test stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]
    @IdRecord BIGINT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
 
    SET @IdRecord = 0;

    EXECUTE  GETNEXTID 1, 1, @IdRecord OUTPUT;
  
    SELECT 'TEST' = @IdRecord;
END
```

And then EXEC the test stored procedure like this:

```
 DECLARE @IdRecord INT

 EXEC [dbo].[TEST] @IdRecord
```